# In cofinite topology on $\mathbb R,$the collection of all open sets is not Locally finite but collection of its closures is locally finite.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

> Give an example of a collection of sets $\mathcal A$ that is not
> locally finite, such that the collection $\mathcal B = \{\bar{A} |
>  A\in  \mathcal A\}$ is locally finite.

**Example**:In cofinite topology on $\mathbb R,$the collection of all open sets is not Locally finite but collection of its closures is locally finite.

$\mathcal Proof$
Let $(\mathbb R,\mathcal T_c)$ be the cofinite topological space on $\mathbb R,$then $\mathcal T_c=\{A\subseteq \mathbb R\ : A=\phi \lor A^c$ is finite},then consider $\mathcal A=\{A:A=\mathbb R$-{finite  points }} then $\mathcal A$ is not locally finite as if $x\in \mathbb R$ ,then any nbhd of $x$ will intersect infintely many elements of $\mathcal A$,these will be $\{A:A=\mathbb R$-{y},$y\neq x$}  and $\mathcal    B=\{\bar A: A\in \mathcal A\}=\{\mathbb R\}$ is locally finite as if $x\in \mathbb R$ ,then any nbhd of $x$ will intersect with only one  element of $\mathcal B$,which is $\mathbb R$.

Please check the proof,also please share other examples if you have any

thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The idea in your proof is fine.  A minor quibble: instead of the collection of all open sets, you may want to consider the collection of all *nonempty* open sets.  Otherwise you would have to consider the empty set explicitly, which is no big deal but unnecessary.

As far as the exposition goes, splitting the whole reasoning into separate sentences would help the reader follow the proof better, instead of mushing the whole reasoning into one continuous string ("...,then ..., then ..., then ..."  Part of learning mathematics is learning to communicate well.  But your ideas are fine.

Note that the same reasoning works for the cofinite topology on any infinite set and not just the reals.

More generally, in any topological space with an example of such a collection $\mathcal A$, one would need to have infinitely many members $A\in\mathcal A$ having the same closure.  If $X$ is a space without isolated points, any subset $A=X\setminus\{x\}$ with $x\in X$ is dense in $X$.  So one can take the collection $\mathcal A$ of all such subsets, and the corresponding collection $\mathcal B=\{X\}$ is finite, hence locally finite.  But in many cases $\mathcal A$ itself will not be locally finite.  Example: all the complements of single points in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb R^2$.